# Sailsjs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js

I'm working with sailsjs,and i use postman i try send to post (http://localhost:1337/user?name=plz)(http://localhost:1337/user?name=plz)(http://localhost:1337/user?name=plz)
but i'm getting error :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.create (C:\Users\achraf\Desktop\crud\cruds\api\controllers\UserController.js:13:29)
at wrapper (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:176:5)
at callbacks (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
at alwaysAllow (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\policies\index.js:158:11)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:176:5)
at callbacks (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
at module.exports (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\cors\clear-headers.js:14:3) [TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined]
```

**UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {

        create:function(req,res){

                var param = req.body.name;
                User.create({name :param.name}).exec(function(err,user){
                        //console.log(success);
                    if(err){

                        res.send("Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong");

                    }else{

                        return res.redirect("/user");

                    }

                });
    }   
};
```

**routes.js**

```
'post /user':   'UserController.create'
```

**User.js(model)**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
        //_id:'p1',
        name:'STRING'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `req.body.name` is returning properly formatted data, you'd want to use `param` instead of `param.name` because you're setting the `name` property directly to the `param` variable.

So do this:

```
var param = req.body.name;
User.create({name : param}).exec(function(err,user){
```

Comment: console.log(req.body) returns null?

Comment: Okay, you're not POSTing the data as per your example above you're GETting the data. Using postman change the request from GET to POST and in the body raw view have a JSON object such as { "name": "foo" }

Comment: In Postman you have few options : form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, binary. Use x-www-form-urlencoded with key/value or raw with application/json header

Comment: can can must pass the data in json in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

use req.params.all(); or use post method in postman and your url will be http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=xyz.

I hope it will solve your problem

module.exports = {

```
    create:function(req,res){

            var param = req.params.all();
            User.create({name :param.name}).exec(function(err,user){
                    //console.log(success);
                if(err){

                    res.send("Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong");

                }else{

                    return res.redirect("/user");

                }

            });
}
```

};

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass "name" using post request, as post man [post man request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE3hA.png)